# show different content when bootstrap 3 modal closes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, savechanges

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I appreciate some help.  I have read the documentation for bootstrap 3 modal. I haven't seen an example of how to do what I'm trying to demo after the user clicks "save" button in a modal.  I am trying to put up a demo that imitates content hiding and showing after a modal closes.  Here is the pseudo code of the use case:

- User clicks `save` button on a page in the UI
- Clicking `save` launches a `modal` window
- User clicks `save` button in the modal (using
  `data-dismiss` attr on "save" btn)
- Modal closes
- Page content (*containing the first save button*) that launched the modal fades
  out and different content fades in.

Is this possible? Not sure if I'm using correct method within modal (`hidden.bs.modal`), or correct `data-*` attribute or where `href` should point within `a` tag. Or if what I am trying to demo is even possible.

All content is on the same page which is set to `display:none`, until I call `fadeIn()` method on the hidden div containing the content I want to show after modal has closed, replacing the initial page content.

Below code is rudimentary and doesn't work, but hopefully if the use case above isn't clear, you can read what I am *trying* to do and help me out.

HTML

```
<a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary savethis">Save</a>
<a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary cancelthis">Cancel</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(".savethis").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
   $("#currContent").fadeOut(function(){
       $("#replacingContent").fadeIn("slow");
   });
   console.log("Modal has completely closed and old content replaced.");
});
```

[Fiddle to view/edit](http://jsfiddle.net/chris2011/srf8hrux/4/)

Comment: Missing a closing quotation mark in the JS

Comment: Also, the modal events are fired at the `<div class="modal">`, not at the trigger `<a>`

Comment: Thanks. I added the missing closing quotation.  Is what I want to do even possible?  If possible, would you mind revising any of my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$('#savethis-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
       $("#currContent").fadeOut("slow");
       $("#replacingContent").fadeIn("slow");
       console.log("Modal has closed and old content replaced.");
})
```

You just made the function weird. It's only one action (FadingOut) happening at the same time of the other (FadingIn). However, notice that this will trigger even if the user clicks on cancel or the exit 'x'. That's because you are binding your actions only to when the modal is hidden. Maybe you should only do that if your user clicked on save.

Heres the Updated Fiddle and it works!. http://jsfiddle.net/srf8hrux/5/

Comment: +1 Leonel Atencio thank you for explaining what I was doing wrong and providing the correct code!  This is exactly what I want to demo. I'll need to tweak the replacingContent -- not sure why it's jumping... should a setTimeout be called so that the new content fades in a few seconds after the modal window has closed?  What do you think?

Comment: You could just insert a delay on the FadeIn function. Some like: $("#replacingContent").delay( 100 ).fadeIn("slow");